# Solving an equation with group theory

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, group-theory, vector-spaces

I have a certain function $F: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and a given nonzero vector $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$. I want to find all vectors $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that
$$
F(a) = F(b)
$$
Is it permissible to assume that I can write
$$
b = Xa
$$
for some $X \in GL(n)$, without losing generality? For any given nonzero $a,b$, there are infinitely many $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ which would map $a$ into $b$, so it seems possible to pick an $X$ which is invertible. If this is permitted, then my problem would become finding a subgroup $G \le GL(n)$ which leaves my function unchanged, $F(a) = F(Ga)$.

I just don't know if this is a good approach to the problem, or if I lose generality by doing this?

Comment: See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2208840) to a somewhat similar question involving group theory but with PGL(2,R).

Comment: For fixed $a$, the set of $G$ such that $F(Ga)=F(a)$ don't necessarily form a group. If $F(G_1a)=F(a)$ and $F(G_2a)=F(a)$, we don't necessarily have $F(G_2G_1a)=F(a)$ do we?

Comment: @Dan: maybe not for an arbitrary $F$. For my specific $F$, which has the property $F(a) = F(Ga) \rightarrow G^T C^T C G = C^T C$ for a given matrix $C$, it will hold that $F(G_2 G_1 a) = F(a)$ (at least in the finite case)

Comment: You can assume that $b=Ga$ but $G$ will depend on $b$. So instead of finding a vector $b$ you will have to find a matrix $G$ which is  harder.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $F$ is linear even though you don't say it.

It is $F(a)=F(b)\Rightarrow F(b-a)=0 \Rightarrow b-a\in Ker(f) \Rightarrow b=a+ker(f)$

So the vectors $b$ you are looking for are of the form $a+x$ where $x\in ker(f)$

Comment: Unfortunately $F$ is not linear - see my edit above

Answer (score 1):

Is $F$ a homomorphism?  If so, the fiber over $F(a)$ is $a+\rm{ker}F$.  This is a special case of a general result.

Comment: I don't think its a homomorphism - see my edit above